# CMDeviceMotion data access

Tags: iphone, swift, accelerometer, gyroscope, motion

I have a problem with access to CMDeviceMotion data. I have everything what is needed included, but my startDeviceMotionUpdates function seems to be passed over (I think that something's wrong with handler). Here is my code:

```
let manager = CMMotionManager()
        if manager.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
            manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()
            manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1
            manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler: {
                    (data, error) -> Void in
                    self.digit.text = String (describing: data!.gravity.z)
                    self.digit2.text = String (describing: data!.gravity.y)
                    self.digit3.text = String (describing: data!.gravity.z)
                    })
```

digit, digit2 and digit3 are edit text fields, where I want my gravity data written into. Everything is tested on iPhone 6 - deviceMotion is aviable and active. I managed to access data without startMotionUpdates function, but i got only NIL value. Any idea what is wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got this. To **access Core Motion** in **Swift 3.0** (using **CMDeviceMotion** class in my case, but can also be **CMGyroData** or **CMAccelerometerData**):

```
let manager = CMMotionManager()
if manager.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
        manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.05 //The lower the interval is, the faster motion data is read 
        manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler: {
            (motion: CMDeviceMotion?, Error) -> Void in

            //Do whatever U want with data provided by CMDeviceMotion

            }
        })
    }
    else{
        print("Core Motion access denied")
    }
```

And don't forget to stop retrieving data from Core Motion if don't needed any more like for example

```
ovveride func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
manager.stopDeviceMotionUpdates()
}
```

Basically, my main problem was with the handler implementation. Hope it helps!

Comment: Elegant solution!

Comment: Nothing to do with the handler implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()
```

Cut it. You will start updates later, when you say:

```
manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: //...
```

What's messing you up is saying *both*.

Comment: Ok, now I'm aware of that - as U can see, I cut that in my solution.

Comment: And to be honest - I tried removing this line before (leaving only manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: //...) and even though it didn't work...

Comment: I am looking right at your original code and at your "solution". There is _no relevant difference_ between them other than the extra `manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()` line.